# How to Disable Emacs elpy Vertical Guide Lines for Indentation?

Tags: emacs, elpy

I am setting Emacs for python development.

So I installed elpy.

But I do not like vertical guide lines for indentation.

How can I disable it or change its color?

[image]

Comment: It is probably a minor mode in addition to `elpy` that causes Emacs to display vertical guides.  Try and figure out what minor modes are active, and then you'll know which one to disable to turn off the vertical guides.  I don't know if you can easily type while in `elpy` something regular such as `M-x describe-mode` or `C-h m` to display the minor modes.  If that doesn't work, perhaps while in `elpy` you can evaluate `(describe-mode)` if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can disable `highlight-indentation-mode` for `elpy-mode`, by adding the following code to your emacs initialization.

```
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook (lambda () (highlight-indentation-mode -1)))
```

EDIT: changed nil to -1

[Source](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/910)

Comment: I added the line to ~/.emacs.d/init.el, however, it still shows vertical guidelines...

Comment: Change `nil` to a negative integer -- e.g., `-1`

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the variable `elpy-modules` to disable the "display indentation markers" module.

Comment: This should be the preferred way to disable the indentation markers over the Tim Miller's answer.

Comment: You can get the current value of `elpy-modules` with `M-x describe-variable RET elpy-modules` (or `C-h v elpy-modules`) and set it in your configuration or with customize.

Comment: `(setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-highlight-indentation elpy-modules))`

Answer (score -1):

M-x customize-face

In the minibuffer enter: highlight-indentation-face

Now you can disable or change as you see fit.

Alternatively, place the cursor into any of the highlighted indentation bars then

M-x customize-face

The argument in the minibuffer should default to the proper value